# Amazon EC2 spot instance request creates itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a spot instance request with my custom AMI (based on Amazon Linux AMI, EBS backed.) When my request was fulfilled, I have another spot instance request created by itself with amzn-ami-pv-2015.09.0.x86_64-ebs (ami-50978202) as AMI with the same bid pricing as the one I created. I didn't really pay attention at the time and since my bid was low ($0.005 per hour) and I only used it for a couple of hours, so I didn't pay attention to it that much.

When I terminated the instance and cancel the request (both the one I created and the one that creates itself,) a new spot instance request with ami-50978202 keeps creating itself no matter how many times I keep canceling it and terminate the instance that was fulfilled. I thought it was because I still have the custom AMI on my account so I tried copying the AMI to another region, but the spot instance creating itself doesn't happen in that region, so I'm quite lost with what's happening here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you by any chance created Auto Scaling Group and add this instance to it? If so, it will create new instance each time the old one is terminated in order to maintain min number of instances specified.

Comment: I don't have any Auto Scaling group set up.

Comment: I've never used spot instances, and I'm not sure if there could be some problem, but if you don't get answer here, I would recommend you to create a case under Amazon "Account and Billing Support", since this issue affects your billing, and you can create such case under your Basic Support Plan which is free. They can directly access your instance and spot request and see what is the problem.

Comment: I contacted the billing department but they were no help. I sort of found an ugly fix but until Amazon address this issue, I don't think there's a good solution.

Comment: Initially their billing support didn't help me to solve the problem too. However, I insisted that the they can't charge me for service that I don't need. I also recorded a screencast showing that terminated instance is replaced by the new one, since they claimed it's not possible to happen. Eventually, they got into my account and fixed the problem. I'm glad that you found a fix for your problem.

Comment: Yes, they eventually figured it out and fixed the problem for me too. Everyone kept assuming that I didn't know how to stop the instance or that I created a persistent request. They gave me a decent credit for my trouble though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to solve your problem but I can confirm that I'm having the exact same issue and I haven't been able to get Amazon to fix the problem all week. It started when I used their new spot instance request system on November 7th. I'm assuming that the system has a bug in it that causes the spot request (not just the instance) to recreate itself. I haven't had problems like this before when creating a spot request. Amazon also thought that I was using an Auto scaling group but I've never set that up either.

The problem is now, trying to get Amazon to respond to this problem. I've opened multiple tickets.  They have only responded one time in a week.  At least they gave me a $12 refund for the time used by the spot instances so far. :-(

Comment: I think the new request system is the issue here. I also did use the new system and that's when the problem occurred.

I contacted the customer service and since I'm on the free tier, I could only reach the billing department and they were no help. I found an ugly fix by deleting the key pair tied to that request and since there's no key pair, the request can't be created again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, cancelling the spot instance would just have it recreate.

At the time of speaking though (2011-12-11) there's an option within `EC2 -> Spot Requests` which looks like a blue speech bubble. Click on that and use the new version.

From there I've been able to cancel the spot request. I just lodged a support ticket asking for a refund for time not used.

Comment: I think this solved the problem for me too. Amazon initially did something, but then in February this problem came back and I now see that going into the blue bubble and going into the beta screen showed the "hidden" spot instance request that wasn't showing up in the main spot instance request screen. Bad Amazon!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't create an ASG (as Zoran mentioned) you probably created a [persistent spot request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html):

> If the request is a persistent request, the request is opened again after your Spot instance is terminated.

Simply [cancel the open spot request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#using-spot-instances-cancel) if you don't want it.

Comment: The request that created itself was persistent. I have tried cancelling it many times, but within 5 minutes of cancelling, another request popped up.

Comment: Adding to that last comment, the step I took was cancel spot request -> terminate instance -> a new spot request creates itself

Comment: You are terminating an instance, you need to cancel the persistent request. Go to the "spot requests" panel, not the "instances" panel. There's a "cancel" button at the top.

Comment: That's what I did as I explained in the previous comment. I apologize if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the answer of @Naypam is the correct one.
I had exactly the same behaviour than @user1274757, @Naypam and @deltaray:

- created a persistent spot request.
- upon cancelation of the "Spot request" from the AWS Web Console by selecting the spot request and pressing the "Cancel" Button:

  - The Spot request is cancelled,
  - a fews minutes later, a new Spot Request is automatically recreated with a new "Request ID" and a new creation timestamp.

This is most probably a bug on the AWS Console.

The work around is the following:

1. On the Web AWS Console, select "Instance > Spot Request"
2. Select the "New Spot Request Console" by clicking the blue bubble on the top-right toolbar and clicking on the "try it out" link that appears.
3. Select the spot request
4. Selection Actions > Cancel Spot Request.

The Spot Request is then really cancelled.
I Have open a case with Amazon and i invite you to do the same.